# Executing PHP script via SSH

Tags: php, file, bash, ssh

I want to send data to my server via SSH. The data is image files that need to be saved into directories on the server.

If I run the script via SSH how can I get a PHP script to read the image files?

For example, if I used bash I could do

```
./uploadimage.bash -image.jpg
```

and that would be that. But my knowledge of PHP is limited. Usually PHP uses the $_FILE array when dealing with files, as far as I know. Do I need to use this if I send the files by SSH?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php

Comment: "I want to send data to my server via SSH."? Do you mean you just want to transfer some files to a server? You can use [`scp`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_copy). Or if you need to transfer more than a few files, then try using [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php), [FileZilla](http://filezilla-project.org/), or [Transmit](http://panic.com/transmit/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the script via php command line executable:

```
php myscript.php image.jpg image2.jpg
```

You can the get the file names via [$argv](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php) array and deal with them any way you please.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you need to do with the images.

- Do you just need to echo them out to the user?

  ```
  echo file_get_contents('image.jpg');
  ```
- Are you meaning to retrieve the command-line variables passed to the script? Use [`$argv`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php).

  ```
  myScript.php image.jpg # image.jpg becomes $argv[1]
  ```
- Do you need to do processing on the images? Use the [GD functions](http://php.net/gd).

  ```
  $image = imagecreatefromjpeg('image.jpg');
  // Do processing
  imagejpeg($image); // Pass a filename if you want to save it instead of output it.
  ```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to simply upload a bunch of files to a remote server, your best bet is to use `scp` command, rather than PHP

```
scp /your/file.png username@host:/remote/path.png
```

If you execute a PHP script through an SSH Session, there's no way you can send a file through SSH. You have to first copy it to the remote server and then execute the PHP which uses `file_get_contents` or something like that.

If you are *sure* that PHP must be the recipient of the file (maybe you want to do some logic to determine the file name, path), you have to host it as a webserver, and you can use `curl` to upload the file, like this:

```
curl -k -F myfile=@image.png foo.php.
```